# Handlings Route Express.js I get response both from try and catch block?

Tags: express, mongoose, routes, controller, try-catch

// server.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });
const app = require("./app");

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.LOCAL_CONN_STRING, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then((conn) => {
    console.log(`Connection successfull with : ${conn}`);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("error is: ", err);
  });

// **************************************
// start the server
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server has started");
});
```

// App.js

```
// import modules.
const express = require("express"); // this is returning a fucntion.
const morgan = require("morgan");

const app = express(); // this is returning app object
const productsRouter = require("./routes/productsRouter");
const customersRouter = require("./routes/customersRouter");
const employiesRouter = require("./routes/employiesRouter");
const addressesRouter = require("./routes/addressesRouter");
const contactsRouter = require("./routes/contactsRouter");
const categoriesRouter = require("./routes/categoriesRouter");
const subCategoriesRouter = require("./routes/subCategoriesRouter");
const ordersRouter = require("./routes/ordersRouter");
const orderProductsRouter = require("./routes/orderProductsRouter");
const paymentsRouter = require("./routes/paymentsRouter");
const pricesRouter = require("./routes/pricesRouter");
const stocksRouter = require("./routes/stocksRouter");

// to use middleware for request body.
app.use(express.json());
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
}
app.use(express.static("./public"));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.requestAt = new Date().toISOString();
  next();
});

app.use("/api/products", productsRouter);
app.use("/api/customers", customersRouter);
app.use("/api/employies", employiesRouter);
app.use("/api/addresses", addressesRouter);
app.use("/api/contacts", contactsRouter);
app.use("/api/categories", categoriesRouter);
app.use("/api/subcategories", subCategoriesRouter);
app.use("/api/orders", ordersRouter);
app.use("/api/orderproducts", orderProductsRouter);
app.use("/api/payments", paymentsRouter);
app.use("/api/prices", pricesRouter);
app.use("/api/stocks", stocksRouter);

// default routes
app.all("*", (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({
    status: "fail",
    data: {
      message: `The requested route (${req.originalUrl}), Not found on the server!`,
    },
  });
});
module.exports = app;
```

// Controller
`

```
createCategory = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name } = req.body;
        const category = await Category.create(
            { name },
        {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
      }
    );
    res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        data: {
            category,
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({
            status: "fail",
            data: {
                error: err.message,
            },
            });
     }
};
```

// Validators are
`

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: {
         type: String,
         required: [true, "category must be specified"],
         minlength: 10,
         maxlength: 100,
         unique: [true, "Category name must be unique"],
      },
  });
```

// console.log(req.body)

```
exports.createCategory = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.body;
    console.log("req.body = ", req.body, "name passsed = ", name);
    const category = await Category.create(
      { name },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
      }
    );
    console.log("pass validation", category);
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        category,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: "fail",
      data: {
        error: err.message,
      },
    });
  }
};
```

results:
"
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`

server has started

Connection successfull with : [object Object]

req.body =  { name: 'Suleyman Sah Furnitures' } name passsed =  Suleyman Sah Furnitures

POST /api/categories/ 404 56.973 ms - 99
"

// response i get from postman is in the image given
 [response i get from postman is in the image given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyjqg.png)

i was expecting the document will be created, and it is created as you can see in the image in mongoDb compass but my catch block still execute, what is wrong here help?

> [i was expecting the document will be created, and it is created as you can see in the image in mongoDb compass but my catch block still execute, what is wrong here help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUKty.png)`

Comment: Can you add the index.js (or server.js or main.js)?

Comment: I added server.js,,,,,, I am coding for my final year project new to development creating my first API  Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you add the result of `console.log("body: ", req.body)`?

Comment: Done bro... req.body is added check it out

Comment: Did you get also same error when you send `Suleyman Sah Furnitures` for the first time?

Comment: yeah bro... for every category i add i get the same response === "error": "Categories validation failed: name: category must be specified"

Comment: all the other routes are working properly but this one made me sick... because i am not able to find the error with this one

Comment: Something is wrong with the validation but i can't get it.... what is the real problem here... i put the same validation for customer it is showing the same response... error msg i put with required field although i already put it there..."customer must be specified"

Comment: Issue is resolved  brother.... Bundles of thanks ❤ for your time and support.... If you want to post it as an answer i'll sent it to you ....

Comment: How did it resolved? What change did you make?

Comment: create method of mongoose only except documents(object in json) and i was passing the optional object in which create() method could not find the name property that why it was throwing an error 'name must be specified',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, the optional object i:e {new: true, runValidators: true } is for the update() method of the mongoose......

Comment: ok by the way `minlength` must be `minLength` and `maxlength` should be `maxLength`

Comment: Thanks brother for your help ... may i ask for your whatsapp.